# Use Gram-Schmidt to replace set S by an Orthogonal set with the same span

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

S =
$
\begin{Bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        5 \\
        -1 \\
        2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}
$

So after doing some work I get:

$v_1 = $
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

$v_2 = 1/5$
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        24 \\
        -6 \\
        9 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

But the answer is the following:

$
\begin{Bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 \\
        -3 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}
$

So is my $v_2$ wrong? Am I missing a step?

Comment: Your work seems to be wrong, because $v_1$ isn't orthogonal to $v_2$.  Show us what you did, please.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps here is the mistake:

$$u_1=\frac{v_1}{\left\|v_1\right\|}=\frac1{\sqrt3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

and now

$$v_2-(v_2\cdot u_1)u_1=\begin{pmatrix}5\\\!-1\\2\end{pmatrix}-\frac136\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\\!-3\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: For some reason my book says $u_1 = v_1$

Comment: @JamesMitchell GS requires unit vectors, so perhaps your book does $$v_2-\frac{v_2\cdot v_1}{\left\|v_1\right\|}v_1$$ which is the same up to **orthogonality**